# Loading a class file immediately AFTER startup

Tags: java, web-applications, web.xml

We have a few war files deployed inside an ear file.  Some of the war files have a class that caches static data from our PLM system in singletons.  Since some of the classes take several minutes to load we use the load-on-startup in the web.xml to load them ahead of time.  This all works fine until we attempt to re-deploy the application on our production servers. (WebLogic 10.3)  We get an exception from our PLM API about a dll already being loaded.  Our PLM vendor has confirmed that this is a problem and stated that they don't support using the load-on-startup.  This is also a huge problem on our development boxes where we have redeploy the app all the time.  Most of us, when we're not working on one of the apps that uses a cache, have them commented out.  Obviously we can't do that for the production servers.  Right now we transfer the ear to the production server, deploy it in the console, wait for it to crash, shut the app server instance down and then start it up again.

We need to find a way around this...

One suggestion was to create a servlet that we can call after the server boots that will load the various caches.  While this will work I'm looking for something a bit cleaner.  Is there anyway to detect once the server started and then fire off the methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a servlet container lifecycle listener, such as [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)?

[Example on how to use](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-servlet/how-to-work-with-servletcontextlistener.html).

EDIT: Sorry, after re-reading your question I don't think this will work. You want something that will load only once per server life, not application life. The ServletContextListener's methods will be called each time the app is deployed, just like a load-on-startup servlet (which it seems you are using). My suggestion will do the exact same thing in a different way.

I would try Chris Nava's suggestion.

EDIT2: It looks like tomcat has some [lifecycle listener](http://tomcat.staging.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/LifecycleListener.html)(s) available to it also. It looks like documentation is sparse, but this potentially would allow you to do something on server startup specifically only once.

EDIT3: Yes, a tomcat lifecycle listener is the way to go. [This link](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/Tomcat55Integration33) explains pretty well how to set one up. Should be fairly straight forward. If you ignore the part about adding the Transaction to tomcat, it goes over pretty thoroughly how to add a lifecycle listener.

Comment: That looks like it should work....I'll give it a shot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem with a third party JDBC driver that loaded a native DLL.  When redeploying the app the driver would crash saying the DLL was already loaded.  The solution (if one can call it that) was to move the driver from deploy into lib.  This way the driver was global to the app server and didn't need to be reloaded when the app was redeployed.